# Loopback: autoupdate value

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback, angular-loopback

I have a model with properties: `status` and `statusId` where statuses can be:

StatusId & Status  are described below:

1. open
2. processing
3. close
4. reject
5. failure

What I want is if I insert or update the **status** of my model then **statusId** should automatically update accordingly.

Comment: use operation hooks. observe('before save') check if the payload contains status then update statusId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two things to implement this scenario

- Making use of Remote hooks for that model using `Observe`

`<model>.observe('before save', function (ctx, next) {
      // check the ctx and add the necessary validations
    }`

- Making use of Middle ware functions if you want this functionality to be like a cross cutting concern for the whole of your app

`app.remotes().before('**', (ctx, next) => {
      // do stuff with ctx.args.options
      next();
    });`